# Angular2 how to know if an input is of type radio with reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am building reactive forms form in angular. I have simple radio button with gender name:

```
this._form = this._formBuilder.group({
            gender: ['', Validators.required]
        });
```

Template:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <h4>What is your gender?</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input value="male" name="gender" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="gender">
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        <span class="custom-control-description">Male</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                        <input value="female" name="gender" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" formControlName="gender">
                        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                        <span class="custom-control-description">Female</span>
                    </label>
                    <app-field-error-display [displayError]="formValidationService.IsFieldInvalid(_form,'gender','required')" errorMsg="Field is required"></app-field-error-display>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I can access the control field by name like this:

```
public GetControl(form: FormGroup, field: string){
        return form.get(field);
    }
```

Based on this how do I access the attribute value of **type="radio"**? I want to know if input control is of type radio.

Comment: Maybe just check by field name ? :D so, if field == 'gender' then it's a radio. Pretty easy, or you want something more generic ?

Comment: generic yes, since i might have 10+ radio buttons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT: This can't be solved with Reactive forms, but you can with Dynamic forms: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form**

**The following is a dirty workarround (not recommended):**

Using native JS with not a good practice in Angular, because you lose a lot of Angular features, but if you're just looking for a quick and dirty fix here it is:

```
public GetControl(form: FormGroup, field: string){
    let el = document.querySelector('input[name="'+field+'"]');
    if(el.getAttribute('type') == 'radio'){
        // This is a radio input
    }
    return form.get(field);
}
```

Comment: yeah i read it's impossible than with native, unless using custom renderer, and refelement is not secure. thanks

Comment: This is not the Angular way to go. Use the form.control or form.value properties.

Comment: @enne87 please read the OP question, he wants to get the input TYPE value not the input value, and this was in 2017 with Angular 2, finally if you have a better approach that answers to that need I am taking it.

Answer (score 13):

*you can access the value by using this code in your component*

```
let genderValue = this._form.value.gender;
```

Comment: im not asking for value of input, i am asking how to check the type of input. how to get "radio" out of input type="radio", aka attribute value.

Comment: [value]="radioItems1" in input tag and radioItems0 = { value: "0"} in component

Comment: again i want to access input type attribute value, not value

Comment: @sensei You should really formulate your question better, cause you said "value" in the question.

Comment: @Enrico I am very late but I updated the title, I hope google refresh it quickly

Answer (score 3):

**A simple one, also provides `intellisense` too**

**Typescript**

```
// declare a form with properties i.e. name
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required]
});

// create getter for form-property i.e.
get Name(): AbstractControl {
     return this.form.get('name')
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="Name">

{{Name.value}} // your can see your input name here
```

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha He asked how do I know the input type is radio using reactive form. I just gave the idea to access reactive-form-field value with ease. By value, he can identify either it is of radio or something else.